# Query does not work with documents

Tags: cmis, nuxeo

So I'm trying to curl some queries. I have 2 documents under a folder which objectId is 8e92c0d5-0fdc-4363-9922-51f9ba93af62.

If I query for the folder itself as in:

```
curl -uAdministrator:Administrator "http://localhost:8282/nuxeo/atom/cmis/default/query?q=SELECT+*+FROM+cmis:folder+f+WHERE+f.cmis:objectId+=+'8e92c0d5-0fdc-4363-9922-51f9ba93af62'" | tidy -q -xml -indent
```

I get the intended result.

However, if I query for the documents under the folder:

```
curl -uAdministrator:Administrator "http://localhost:8282/nuxeo/atom/cmis/default/query?q=SELECT+*+FROM+cmis:document+d+WHERE+IN_FOLDER(d,+'8e92c0d5-0fdc-4363-9922-51f9ba93af62')" | tidy -q -xml -indent
```

I get no results, even though there are 2 documents under it.

Is there some setting I forgot to turn on? Or am I doing something completely wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `&searchAllVersions=true` to your URL. See [the Nuxeo CMIS doc](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/JIAO) about the use of `searchAllVersions` in Nuxeo.